# Simplify $(A+C)(AD+AD) + AC + C$ using Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra, solution-verification

I have solved the equation like this:

```
 (A + C)(AD + AD) + AC + C
=(A + C)(AD) + (A + C)(AD) + AC + C
=AAD + ACD + AAD + ACD + AC + C
=AAD + AAD + ACD + ACD + AC + C
=AAD + ACD + AC + C 
=AAD + ACD + C(A+1)
=AAD + ACD + C
=AD + ACD + C
=AD(1+C) + C
=AD + C
```

Am I right?

Comment: Definitely boolean algebra you want?

Comment: @stevemarvell I want to solve the equation using laws of Boolean algebra. Have I solved it correctly?

Comment: You might want to consider the truth of AA

Comment: @stevemarvell Just edited it. Is it perfect now?

Comment: consider the simplification of (AD + ACD)

Comment: now it looks great

Comment: Three of the steps were completely unnecessary (it involves an idempotent.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks just fine! Well done!

A bit more simply, $$\begin{align}(A+C)(AD+AD)+AC+C &= (A+C)AD+AC+C\\ &= AAD+CAD+AC+C\\ &= AD+(AD+A+1)C\\ &= AD+C\end{align}$$

Comment: It can be simplified a great deal more than that.

Comment: Really? How can $AD+C$ be simplified?

Comment: The question has been edited since my comment.

Comment: You probably just needed to refresh your page. I had the same thing happen to me. Initially, I mentioned that two pairs of terms had common factors, which allowed further simplification, but after posting the answer, the page automatically refreshed and showed that the OP had noticed that and acted accordingly, so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would have taken the following steps:
$$
\begin{align}
   (A + C)(AD + AD) + AC + C
&= (A + C)(AD) + (AC + C)\\
&= AD + ADC + C\\
&= AD + C\\
\end{align}
$$